# dual boot, dual drive Macbook pro unibody mid 2012

Tags: linux, macos, multi-boot

I have recently bought a new SSD for my macbook pro, and plans to put my old HDD in a caddy and place it on the optical drive slot.

In my old HDD is ParrotOS and some important files. I plan to install Catalina on the SSD

I tried installing linux and MacOS in the same drive in the past, but Failed miserably. This way, it will be at different drives, and different file formats, so it wont interfere with each other. I have slow internet and cant afford to download large files regularly.

What are the available resources to download to have smoother Boot Switching between the two OS?

Comment: Most use the grub bootloader

Comment: should i install it on the mac or linux side? or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macs have a builtin Startup Manager that can be accessed by holding down the option key at startup. This will detect an installation of macOS on either drive and will permit you to select to boot. You can test to see if your existing ParrotOS installation is compatible with the Startup Manager by booting to the Startup Manager. If compatible, then the ParrotOS will appear as a selection. Usually, the label will be `EFI Boot`.

If the builtin Startup Manager will not detect the ParrotOS installation, then you can try installing the [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Boot Manager. This boot manager can usually detect any linux installation.